# Is it possible to recreate activity and keep the runtime instance?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences, android-theme

I create a SettingsActivity to let the users set the preferences.
One of the preference is skin color.

```
    Intent settingIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(settingIntent);
```

Once the user finish setting, he\she would tap the "done" button to go back to the MainActivity.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    intent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

But the MainActivity doesn't really change.

I realize that I only apply the change in onCreate()

```
    setTheme(SettingsActivity.getSkinColor()); // Get the preference from SharedPreference
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
```

In this case, I think I have to recreate the activity. So I change **intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)** to **intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)**.

However, it will create a new MainActivity when user tap "done" button.

Is there a way to apply the setTheme without recreating activity? Or at least keep all the run time instance and state when I create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Extras to the intent to give the newly started Activity the runtime state and the theme information it needs to configure itself properly.

Comment: If I still want to use intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) to restore the activity in stack. Is there a way to pass data by using intent.putExtra(). Or is there a way to set a callback when I dismiss the setting activity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to force recreating your activity.

In `onResume()` of your main activity you could check to see if the theme has been changed. If so, just call `setTheme()` and then `setContentView()` again, and this will recreate your layout with the new theme. Remember to redo all your `findViewById()` calls because all your `View` objects have been recreated.

Comment: Assuming I call setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light). How can I check if the theme is changed to another resId?

Comment: You can call `getTheme()` in `onCreate()` and remember that in a member variable. In `onResume()` call `getTheme()` again and compare.